# How to zip and deploy a dist artefact after appassembler-maven-plugin:assemble

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I have a multi-module Maven project.

In the lastly executed module, I assemble the dist directory using the [Appassambler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/).

Then I'd like to zip it and deploy as a maven artifact.

I'm about to simply zip it somehow and then use `deploy:deploy-file`.

**Are there any more maven-like alternatives?**

I've seen the combination of [Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) and `deploy:deploy`, but it seems that shade is quite hard to persuade to zip particular directory.

I'm open to any solution of the whole "assemble, zip and deploy" process.

Comment: Using the appassembler plugin for creation of a dist directory sounds wrong. Creating zip/whatever archive is maven-assembly-plugin's job. Can you show what you already tried ? May be having a git hub project?

Comment: Sure, [here](http://code.google.com/p/jawabot/source/browse/#git%2Fassemble). As you can see, I've tried all plugins I've found. I don't like assemble plugin as I have to re-declare what I want to package in an external file. Appassemble just takes current module's deps and some files and puts it to a dir. But it could be that I didn't get the concept right.

Comment: The appassembler plugin is not intended for creation of archives its intention is to [create scripts to start applications](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/). After taking a look into the project i understand that you're having problems, cause you dindn't understand some basics in Maven (life-cycle, inheritance, packaging), resource and java code separation etc. That is the root cause of your problems. Not Maven itself. Sorry to say.

Comment: No, I understand Maven quite well, just not these assembling plugins. Java code separation from resources is a nonsense, I don't do it and we don't do it in the company unless it has sense, e.g. separated web design team. For standalone apps, it hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am quite in favor of Maven, I have to say that all Maven tools for creating an app distribution I've found, aren't satisfying. Either they are buggy, or poorly documented, or user hostile.

I have resorted to the concept I read, where the directory prepared by appassemble plugin is zipped using Ant (assembly-plugin fails at this too) and then added as one of module's artefacts.

Here's my solution, however I'll keep the question opened if someone wants to prove me wrong and provide a solution using standard Maven plugins, thanks.

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution> <id>createDistJar</id> 
                    <goals> <goal>run</goal> </goals>  <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="${project.build.directory}"/>
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}"/>
                            <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/JawaBot-${project.version}-dist.zip"
                                basedir="target/" includes="JawaBot-${project.version}-dist-rh/**">
                            </zip>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>uploadDistJar</id> <goals>  <goal>attach-artifact</goal>  </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>${project.build.directory}/JawaBot-${project.version}-dist.zip</file>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: [Just as an example](https://github.com/khmarbaise/supose) take a look at supose-assembly which creates zip file etc. with script which have been created by appassembler-plugin. may be you can give more information about the problems you had (buggy? Missing things ?)

Comment: Yes, I intend to, as every time I have to create a dist zip with Maven, it gets frustrating, so I will complain to some blog soon :)

Comment: Better is to file in issues in the bug tracking system (plugins, etc) if you found bugs for the plugins. if you are missing things do it the same way.

Comment: Well, TBH, I have given up  filing maven bugs, some are there for 4 years, and it only got better when one of Sonatype founders came to my company and I could bug him directly (kudos to him :)